# Issue when reading yaml from jenkins pipeline - Could not determine a constructor for the tag !Ref

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to **read** a Yaml file during Jenkins build using **readYaml** function and getting below error:

Stacktrace:

```
could not determine a constructor for the tag !Ref
 in 'reader', line 7, column 12:
        Value: !Ref AutoScalingGroup
               ^

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructUndefined.construct(SafeConstructor.java:511)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:375)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:151)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:356)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:493)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:375)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:151)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:356)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:493)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:375)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:151)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:356)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:493)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:143)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:110)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.shaded.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:472)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.conf.ReadYamlStep$Execution.doRun(ReadYamlStep.java:133)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Jenkins code:**

```
script{
        def filename = 'adminData.yaml'
        def data = readYaml file: filename //getting error when reading
        println "${data.Version}"
        data.Version = '1.2'
        writeYaml file: filename, data: data , overwrite: true
        }
```

**Yaml file:**

```
Version: '2010-09-09'
Description: New stack

Outputs:
  AppServerGroup:
    Description: App Server Group
    Value: !Ref AutoScalingGroup

Parameters:
  Active:
    Description: Whether or not this ASG is Active
    Type: String
  EnvType:
    Description: S3 config swap bucket suffix
    Type: String
    Default: dev
```

This yaml file is a predefined file which contains !Ref, !Equals and others similarly which causes same error. I just want to read this yaml and modify its version number for every jenkins build dynamically. Please help me overcome this error or any alternative approaches to read/write yaml will also be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the same yaml parser as in application. Or put your !Ref... Value in quotes.

Comment: Your yaml file is AWS CloudFormation Template which is upon on Yaml, but not pure YAML, like `!Ref`, `!Sub`  is not recognized by default/build-in Yaml Parser provided by yaml package